# cart empty after payment fail issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment

My cart is empty after payment fail. I want the cart quantity in quote after payment fail.

I'm using the **PayUMoney Payment Method**.
How can I do this?

Please share the quick solution.

Comment: there is a solution in magento 1.x but  not sure how to implement in Magento 2 let me check http://ka.lpe.sh/2011/12/31/magento-getting-back-shopping-cart-items-after-order-fails/

Comment: which module , you have using?

Comment: @AmitBera  Magestore_OneStepCheckout Module

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension.html

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Any update for that?

Comment: cart empty after payment fail it's resolved in magento1 but no solution for magento2 if I find any solution then I will inform you